# Code is not printing Please enter in your annual sales, but builds successfully

Tags: java, printing, build, println

I have my code which is suppose to print the line, "Please enter in your annual sales."  After entering the input it is suppose to then run through the calculations..I am sure I am missing something but I am not sure what...Help please!

```
   /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package annualcompensation;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    /*
     * This program will calculates the total annual compensation  
     * of a salesperson. It will ask the user to enter annual sales, 
     * and it will display the total annual compensation for the 
     * salesperson.
     */


    public class AnnualCompensation {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
     double fixedSalary;//Declares a double variable named fixed salary.
     double annualSales;//Declares a double variable named annual sales.
     double commission; //Declares a double variable named comission.


        public void AnnualCompensation()
        {
            // The salesperson earns the fixed yearly salary of $60,000
            fixedSalary = 60000.00;
        }

            // The salesperson's yearly sales will be displayed
        public double getyearlySales(){
            return annualSales;
        }

            // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        public void readData(){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter in your annual sales: ");
            // The program will the print the salesperson's annual sales
            annualSales = input.nextInt();
        }

       public void calculateCommission() {
            // Indicates salesperson's commission is 5% of thier annual sales
            commission = 0.5 * annualSales;
        }

        public double getCommission(){
            return commission;
        }

            // The program will display salesperson's total annual compensation
        public double getTotalAnnualCompensation (){
            return fixedSalary + getCommission();
            }


      public class SimpleCalculation {

         public void main(String[] args) {
            // Creat a new object AnnualCompensation
            AnnualCompensation acct = new AnnualCompensation();
            // ask user to enter annual sales and get data
            acct.readData();
            // calculate commission of sales
            acct.calculateCommission();
            // Display the total annual compensation
            System.out.println("The the total annual compensation is: $" +      acct.getTotalAnnualCompensation());

        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: What does it print out currently?

Comment: It doesn't print anything, it just shows 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)'

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2.

Comment: @TiaraOakes - No. I mean how are you *executing the program*?. You have to run / execute it

Comment: @TiaraOakes in netbeans go to AnnualCompensation class right click and run the class file

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar  Run > Run Project

Comment: @Soorapadman the project runs, however it is not printing any output of any kind.  It only shows the build was successful.

Comment: @TiaraOakes - Right click on the `main()` method and click `run()` (or RUn as java application)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar is there is difference between run() or running as java application?

Comment: @TiaraOakes - I am a big fan of eclipse (so never used netbeans). Yes, you should try "run as java application which will probably work".

Comment: I see.  It appears that the option to 'run as a java application is an option in Eclipse.  The similar way to do that is to run the .JAR  from Windows.  I got the JAR file and copied it to the root folder and tried to run it and nothing happens.  I think I may have some bad syntax but I am not sure what is wrong. @VinodMadyalkar

Comment: @TiaraOakes - *From the IDE's menu bar, choose Run | Run Main Project.*. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html)